# Time complexity of sorting algorithms

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have two questions regarding time complexities.

1) I still haven't seem to have gotten a hold of the big-oh or the landau's notation. I know it is used to represent time complexities, but why cant I just say the worst-case time complexity of, say, bubble sort is n^2 and not as O(n^2)?

2) Why does log come into the picture for some time complexities? for example, why and how exactly is the worst-case time complexity of shell sort O(nlogn)?

any good site, other than wikipedia, about these things will be appreciated.

Comment: and what is wrong with wikipedia??

Comment: I will give you a +1 for your question because it is very natural to have a question like what you have when you are doing analysis of algorithms. I dont know why some people start giving "-" votes. The intent of the author posting the question is very clear he wants to understands from where does log stuff come in and how does it come in while calculating time complexities.

Comment: UmNyobe, I know i will get my answers on SO, but I needed explanations, hence i asked. n wikipedia is vague sometimes.
@Yavar, thanks for understandin my situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Big-O notation is used to denote the fact that you're talking about *asymptotic behaviour*.  If you just write `n^2`, it might be assumed that you're talking about the actual runtime of your particular program (i.e. that you could get the runtime in seconds directly from that expression).  But in practice, your runtime will be of the form `a.n^2 + b.n + c.log(n) + d`.  Big-O notation allows you to ignore all the lower-order terms, because as `n` heads to infinity, it's only the `n^2` term that matters.
2. I'm not sure the worst-case complexity of shell sort is `O(n log n)`.  But `log` often comes in when something is being successively divided in two (think about the height of a balanced binary tree, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

This site gives you a very good feel of what complexity is.

Comment: From this website: The worse-case time complexity of shell sort depends on the increment sequence. For the increments 1 4 13 40 121..., which is what is used here, the time complexity is O(n3/2). For other increments, time complexity is known to be O(n4/3) and even O(n·lg2(n)). Neither tight upper bounds on time complexity nor the best increment sequence are known.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through: http://betterexplained.com/articles/demystifying-the-natural-logarithm-ln/

This (& other math stuff in the same website above) will demystify stuff like e, log, ln, d/dx, Big-O, Rate of Growth etc in a fundamental way with lot of practical stuff relating to real world.

Answer (score 0):

You should know the difference between these two statements:

1. The complexity of an algorithm is n^2 and
2. The **order** of the complexity of an algorithm is O(n^2).

So in your first question O(n^2) represents the **order** of the complexity not the complexity itself.

Second question

Sometimes the solution for any problem like (Binary search) create a tree like structure. This structure means the original problem is being divided into **n smaller** problems and they are solved independently. These smaller problems can further be divided in sub-problems and solved independently.
So, the number n makes the base of the logarithm.
Thus to solve the original problem the whole tree has to be solved and here comes the concept of logarithms, because logarithms make it easy to solve these tree like problems.